# Angular Momentum conservation in star system

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, planets, stars

This question is related to what happens to a planetary body(like earth) when the star it is orbiting collapses under its own gravity.

Suppose a star is rotating about its axis with some angular velocity. Suppose a planet orbiting the star has the same angular velocity as that of the star about the axis of the star. So an observer on the planet will observe the star to be stationary with respect to him.

Now if the star collapses under its own gravity, considering isotropic collapse, from our lab frame of reference the angular velocity of the star about its axis should increase because angular momentum has to be conserved. But for the observer on the planet, since the total angular momentum of the star about its axis is zero it should remain zero. Hence the planet should move with higher angular velocity and the a decreased distance from the star.

Is this reasoning correct? What if i replace planet with just an observer?

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> But for the observer on the planet, since the total angular momentum of the star about its axis is zero it should remain zero.

But the observer on the planet does not occupy an inertial frame. An observer in a rotating frame measures [fictitious forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force). So there is no reason why angular momentum should be conserved.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be neglecting the change in the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) of the planet in the definition of angular momentum:
$$
\mathbf L=I\boldsymbol\omega
$$
Since $\boldsymbol\omega$ increases, then $I$ must decrease to satisfy angular momentum conservation. There isn't any need for angular momentum to somehow "reach out" and take it from a nearby planet.